# What is the BLuetooth specification of latest Android support?

Tags: android, bluetooth

As shown in title, What is the BLuetooth specification (core specification 4.0 or 4.2) of latest Android (7.0 or 6.0) support?

THe default bluetooth stack is AndroidBlue now, while the latest Bluetooth stack BLuez supports the Bluetooth specification 4.2. It means that in connection state, the slave role can operating **with multiple masters**. And there can be multiple bluetooth state suppport (as defined in core 4.2, vol6, partB).

I wander know whether the latest version of Andorid support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on my reading of specs it looks like Android 6.0 supports Bluetooth Core 4.1 specification.

The specs come from http://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth.html and the document http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//devices/Android-6.0-Bluetooth-HCI-Reqs.pdf . Presumably when the Android Compatibility Definition Document for 7.0 is released: http://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd.html changes to the Bluetooth specification will be updated as well.